# Every time I open or switch to IDLE it spams Q

Tags: python

I'm on Windows, using WLS Ubuntu on terminal. Got python3 installed. Installed idle through

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

Every time I open IDLE through typing 'idle' in the terminal, or alt tab to IDLE, or run a .py file through IDLE, it starts spamming the letter Q. I wasn't able to reproduce this issue in any other program.

I tried reinstalling IDLE, to no avail.

Is there a fix for this? I want to keep using IDLE but this is driving me mad!